# I'm trying to figure out what the easiest way to go about creating this type of video would be. I can't find a tutorial. Please help!

Tags: after-effects, animation

This [video I'm trying to recreate](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZXqQGuAt7SE) seems like an insanely time consuming process in after effects.  Is AE the right way to go about it?  Does anyone know of a process or tutorial that may help?  I'm new to video production so any sort of direction would be greatly appreciated.  Here is [another similar type of video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gWTM8ToMAns).  Generally speaking a VoiceOver text video.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The Typemonkey script will get you most of the way there, but ultimately there is no “just animate” button in After Effects. It’s designed to give you lots of control over how everything looks and moves.

http://aescripts.com/typemonkey/

Otherwise look for Kinetic Typography tutorials like this one: